# greater than or equal to in java using double

Tags: java

I am trying to use <= sign for a variable. After stating:

```
double ta = input.nextDouble();
```

I am trying to limit ta by using double as:

```
double ta = -58>=ta>=41.
```

I tried a couple of ways, I tried putting Boolean instead of double and tried to break them into 2 statements. I am using java and I am a beginner.

Comment: Are you trying to clamp the input to the range or simply reject it if it is out of range?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you would structure it. Currently you are trying to assign a boolean value to a double.

```
double ta = input.nextDouble();
if (ta <= -58 || ta >= 41) {
  //error, not in range
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that `<=` and `>=` are operators which take two numerical values and returns a `boolean`. With that in mind, let's look at what you are trying to do:

```
-58>=ta>=41
```

Because `>=` is an operator, it also has an assigned "order of operations", similar to the idea you learn in a basic algebra class. In particular, the above statement is the same as

```
(-58>=ta)>=41
```

The result of the part in parentheses is a `boolean`. So the compiler thinks you are trying to compare a `boolean` to an `int`, which of course doesn't make any sense. This is the reason you get an error.

Now to fix the problem, you need to back up and look more closely at the logic of the comparison you are trying to make. Most likely, you want to see if the input is less than -58 OR bigger than 41. If either of these are true, then you know the input is invalid and you want to deal with it appropriately, perhaps by asking for the input again.

Now that we have the condition in words, you can see that you need an if statement with the following condition:

```
ta <= -58 || ta >= 41
```

You may even need to split this into two separate cases if you want to take a different action depending whether `ta` is below the lower bound or is above the upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

To clamp `ta` to a range you can do this:

```
ta = Math.max(-58, Math.min(41, ta));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. The syntax is called a *ternary*:

```
ta = -58 < ta || ta > 41 ? 41d : ta;
```

Your attempt redeclared the `ta` variable - I removed the keyword `double` from the statement

You could express it as a `if` to make it easier to understand

```
if (-58 < ta || ta > 41)
    ta = 41;
```

Comment: It's difficult to see from the OP if this answer gives the desired behavior. My guess is that we would want to do something more like `if (-58 < ta) ta = -58;` in the case of the lower bound.